# How to best store app wide accessible variables and arrays in Swift

Tags: swift

I have a few defined arrays and/or variables that I would like to access from across the app. Typically they will be used to populate UIPicker options. What is the most efficient way to store these for global access within the app?

eg. activityType = ["Run", "Swimming", "Cycling"]

Comment: I gave you a bunch of options but if you can be more specific on the use case I can help tell you which method is better to use.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a class and within that class have a static variable like this:

```
class Activity: NSObject {

    var activityType = ["Run", "Swimming", "Cycling"]

    static var shared = Activity()
}
```

To access this property simply use this line `Activity.shared.activityType`

Keep in mind a class is a reference type opposed to a value type so it will act slightly different from the array you created locally but in most cases this shouldn't effect you. If you absolutely need a value type you can use a struct. You can modify the array the same way you would otherwise modify an array `Activity.shared.activityType = ["new val", "newvla2"]`.

This will persist across your app.

You can also store them as global variable. This is generally not considered best practice but sometimes it is just the easiest way to do it.

Here is how you would do that:

```
let activityType = ["Run", "Swimming", "Cycling"]

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    //Do whatever you want here for you VC 
}
```

You can also just create a struct or class with the values in them if you don't plan on modifying them.

```
class Activity: NSObject {
    let activityType = ["Run", "Swimming", "Cycling"]
}
```

Or

```
struct Activity {
    let activityType = ["Run", "Swimming", "Cycling"]
}
```

Comment: I gave an upvote.  I also include final and a private init.  Final prevents it from being subclassed and private init ensures it's unique.  Important since its app wide.  

`final class Activity: NSObject {
    static let shared = Activity()
    private init () {}
}`

Answer (score 0):

If they are constants a common practice is to put them into a struct containing static members. e.g.

```
struct K {
    static let string1 = "some text"
    static let integer1 = 1
    static let array1 = ["a","b","c"]
}
```